# Validation in Delphi

Tags: validation, delphi

I'm a student and stuck on Delphi Validation. Here is my code:

```
begin
valid := true;
for I:=1 to Length(edtvalue.Text) do
if not (edtvalue.Text[I] in ['0'..'9','.'] )then
valid:= false;
if not valid then
begin
  showmessage ('This item is not within the range');
  DataItem1 := 0;
end
else
dataitem1 := strtofloat(edtvalue.Text);
```

This code reads in a value that the user inputs and checks whether it actually is an integer and detects when a user inputs letters.

However when the user inputs something else (e.g. + or @) the code doesn't work and breaks the system. Is there a way I can fix this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use TryStrToFloat

Comment: And in addition, don't check for '.'. The decimal separator might be a different character. Using TryStrToFloat will take care of that too.

Comment: What does "breaks the system" mean? Your second paragraph send to contradict your third paragraph. If you intend to check for integers, then why are you counting to a floating-point type and not an integral type?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TryStrToFloat` :

```
var
  F: Double;
begin
     if not TryStrToFloat(edtvalue.Text, F) then
         showmessage ('This item is not within the range');
     else
         dataitem1 := F; 
end;
```

Or if you want to set DataItem1 to 0 when error :

```
var
  F: Double;
begin
     if not TryStrToFloat(edtvalue.Text, F) then
       begin
         showmessage ('This item is not within the range');
         DataItem1 := 0;
       end
     else
         dataitem1 := F; 
end;
```

Also you can create a `Function` to do that , like :

```
function IsFloat(Str: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Double;
  C: Integer;
begin
  Val(Str, I, C);
  Result := C = 0;
end;
```

Comment: You need to fix this code somewhat, and why would you need a temp variable? And why use Extended?

Comment: I think my code work fine , and Yes I can use `Double` instead.

Comment: Nope. Read it closely.

Answer (score 1):

I changed to use `TryStrToFloat` as recommended by David in the comments, you just need to declare that `val` variable:

```
var
  val: Extended;
begin
    val := 0;
    if not TryStrToFloat(edtvalue.Text, val) then
        showmessage ('This item is not within the range');
    dataitem1 := val; 
end;
```

Comment: No, that's not right. You don't loop, just pass the entire blue to TryStrToFloat

Comment: Why not remove the loop and use just `TryStrToFloat` ?

Comment: My bad, just fixed it.

Comment: @Sami indeed, I was unaware of `TryStrToFloat` and fixed their code with a `break` in the loop (it was missing it), but after I read David's comment and searched for `TryStrToFloat`, it really simplifies a lot, I just didn't think quickly enough to see I wouldn't need the loop anymore.

Comment: No , I think you edit your code when I post my answer , and that the same code I post it.

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer when I first edited removing the loop, but indeed I fixed because you and @DavidHeffernan alerted me, which I should thank you both.

Comment: You don't need to `val := 0` if you use `If else` , and where is `;` ?

Comment: Also, @DavidHeffernan if `dataitem1` was a property/field of some class (like the `TForm`), would it still work?

Comment: @Sami thanks, I fixed it. If the `TryStrToFloat` fails, `dataitem1` is set with zero, that's why I initialize `val`. As far as I know, if you don't initialize it, since it's a variable in a function (not a property, for example), it might come which random values from memory instead of zero. In your approach you don't need, because you only use the `F` if `TryStrToFloat` is successful.